# ¿Por qué "ir tajado" o "llevar una buena tajada" es "ir borracho"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa

¿Por qué cuando alguien va borracho decimos que "lleva una "buena" tajada encima" o que "va tajado"?

*[Tajada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Yxb5clh)*, según el DRAE tiene (entre otros) el significado de

> 4. f. coloq. Embriaguez, borrachera.

Según [*Etimologías de Chile*](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?tajada) (y la propia RAE) *tajada* no es más que el participio del verbo [tajar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YxogHjF), que significa "cortar", que viene además del latín *taleare* (talar).

¿Cómo ha llegado el verbo entonce a asociarse con el estado de embriaguez?

Soy consciente que *Etimologías de Chile* propone<sup>1</sup> que es porque alguien "lleva ya encima su porción o ración de bebida alcohólica". La expresión "ir cargado" a veces se usa con el mismo sentido (ir borracho/intoxicado) y entiendo que puede ser por lo mismo: "ir cargado de alcohol". Sin embargo, "ir tajado" es literalmente, ir cortado o "talado" con lo cual deja de tener tanto sentido esa asociación.

Otra cosa interesante es que la expresión suele usarse como que alguien "lleva una **buena** tajada". Si se dijese solo "lleva una tajada" la frase parece que pierde un poco de su expresividad en la referencia alcohólica, y cabría preguntarse "¿una tajada de qué?".

¿Existen otras referencias o fuentes que puedan explicar por qué "ir tajado" o "llevar una buena tajada" significa "ir borracho"?

---

<sup>1: Aunque ellos mismos admiten que no están completamente seguros de que ese sea el origen y que lo que proponen es una *suposición*.</sup>

Comment: En Andalucía se usa bastante: _Menúa tajá lleva_. :-)

Comment: How curious that we use _half-cut_ to mean drunk, at least in South-East England. Either the two usages arose spontaneously independently or perhaps they have a common root.

Answer (score 3):

La acepción de ***tajada*** como sinónimo de "borrachera" es relativamente reciente: de [todos los usos que aparecen en el CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=4&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=030717%5C011%5CC003O03072017114101777.1172.1168&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20tajada%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&marcas=0), el más antiguo que he visto claramente con ese significado data [de 1954](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=644&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=030717%5C011%5CC003O03072017114101777.1172.1168&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20tajada%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto644):

> - Pero ¿todavía queréis otra? Anda ya, muchachos, que os vais a poner nuevos. Esta tarde os la vais a tener que pasar durmiendo la **tajada**.

No aparece dicha acepción en el [diccionario de 1854](https://books.google.es/books?id=orcGAAAAQAAJ&dq=diccionario%20lengua%20castellana&hl=es&pg=PA658#v=onepage&q&f=false) tampoco (el último que puedo consultar via Google Books), lo cual vendría a confirmar que su incorporación se produjo en los últimos 100 años.
EDIT: confirmado, tras consultar el NTTLE (gracias [Gonzakas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/17125/gonzakas)), que la primera aparición de ***tajada*** como sinónimo de "borrachera" aparece [en 1901 en el diccionario de Toro y Gómez](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltNavegacion?numReg=5&diccionario=75&hoja=775&columna=1&creaCn=SI&operacion=14&sec=1.2.1.0.0.&). Al final incluyo unas notas sobre esto.

Así las cosas, resulta complicado establecer un origen. Desde luego, no es por razones de etimología. ¿Podría ser por el significado literal de "porción", como propone Etimologías de Chile? Podría, pero me sorprendería un poco que así fuera; pues siendo "porción" el significado que ha tenido la palabra durante al menos los últimos cuatrocientos años, choca que nadie la haya usado antes para referirse a "porción de bebida" al hablar de una borrachera.

***DISCLAIMER***: Lo siguiente es pura conjetura.

Mi sensación, tras leer los usos del CORDE, es que **en algún momento empezó a usarse popularmente en su acepción de "ronquera ocasionada por un resfriado", a modo de retranca, para referirse a la típica voz gangosa y dificultad en el habla que muestran las personas cuando van borrachas**. La típica gracia que se nos ocurre a los españoles. De hecho, aún hoy en día se oye a veces usar la excusa de un resfriado para justificar una melopea.
Dicha expresión se iría popularizando, hasta el punto de usarse como sinónimo y ser recogida por el DLE como cuarta acepción de la palabra.

Esa es mi teoría, al menos.

---

Existe un uso en el CORDE, [de 1920](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=605&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=030717%5C011%5CC003O03072017114101777.1172.1168&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20tajada%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto605), que sí podría confirmar la interpretación de EdC:

> Pul.- ¿Marcharte? ¿Marcharte cuando te esperamos como la joven esposa espera el fruto que lleva en sus entrañas; como el caravanero el oasis; como el pescador la ballena?...
>   Clau.- Sí, sí, comprendido; como el beodo la **tajada**.

Aquí yo entiendo que el beodo desea su porción, como el pescador desea la ballena, por ejemplo. No tendría mucho sentido que el beodo espere su borrachera: ¡ya está borracho! Pero entonces ¿su porción de qué?

Lo normal sería pensar que de bebida; este uso sería una excepción, pues, en todos los usos anteriores y posteriores (hasta el referido de 1954), "tajada" como porción se usa siempre refiriéndose a comida, no a bebida.
Podría ser su porción de comida, por querer acompañar la bebida con algo, pero perdería fuerza entonces el símil.

En cualquier caso, aquí su uso es todavía el literal de "porción". Si este uso es el que dio lugar posteriormente a la expresión "llevar una buena tajada" o no, sigue estando de momento en el terreno de las hipótesis sin confirmar (igual que la mía).

---

**Adenda**

Consultando el NTTLE me encuentro con que la expresión [«***tener una buena tajada***» aparece tal cual en el diccionario Zerolo de 1985](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltNavegacion?numReg=4&diccionario=70&hoja=2003&columna=3&creaCn=SI&operacion=14&sec=1.2.1.0.0.&), pero **no** con el significado de "borrachera" sino con el de «*tener un empleo lucrativo*». ¿Quizá el origen de la expresión sea en referencia a los efectos de la, ejem, "celebración" que la gente hacía al conseguir un buen empleo?

Por otra parte, aunque el significado de "borrachera" ya aparece en 1901, da la sensación de que no estaba muy extendido su uso: [el diccionario Alemany y Bolufer de 1917 no recoge la acepción](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltNavegacion?numReg=6&diccionario=86&hoja=1553&columna=1&creaCn=SI&operacion=14&sec=1.2.1.0.0.&) a pesar de ser posterior, mientras que [el Rodríguez Navas de 1918 sí la incluye](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltNavegacion?numReg=7&diccionario=88&hoja=1697&columna=1&creaCn=SI&operacion=14&sec=1.2.1.0.0.&)...

Nada de esto ayuda a aclarar el origen de la expresión, pero es interesante igualmente.

Comment: puedes consultar diccionarios anteriores mediante el "Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico" de la Real Academia Española: [**NTLLE**](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle)

Answer (score 1):

En el [blog del listo que todo lo sabe](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/tag/melopea/), explican que en la antigüedad, como las bebidas alcohólicas solían acompañarse de algún alimento, empezó a asociarse la "tajada" como porción de comida o "tapa" (porción o corte de embutido, queso o carne) que se ponía para acompañar la bebida con la propia bebida alcohólica. Con el tiempo esa vinculación convirtió a la medida de vino en el resultado de su ingesta (la borrachera).

> [...] por lo que nacieron numerosos refranes, como por ejemplo *‘Buen vino y buena tajada y no apurarse por nada’* (aquí la tajada del refrán hace referencia a la comida no a la borrachera).
>
> Cuando alguien llegaba a la taberna era típico que pidiese ‘*una jarra de vino y una tajada’* y no se sabe a ciencia cierta por qué ni cuándo, pero **esa porción de alimento (o sea, la tajada) con el tiempo sirvió para denominar también a la porción o medida de vino**, convirtiéndose en habitual el que se pidiera directamente *‘una tajada de vino’*
>
> Con el tiempo, **esa vinculación convirtió a la medida de vino en el resultado de su ingesta**, siendo, posteriormente, el término tajada una de las muchas formas con las que conocemos el estado de embriaguez o borrachera.

Así que de acuerdo a esta entrada no se debe a que alguien "lleva ya encima su **porción o ración** (tajada) de bebida alcohólica", si no a la asociación con la tajada de comida o ración que se ponía a modo de tapa.

Answer (score 0):

En España, en la época de la "reconquista" cuando acechaban a los moriscos, éstos, amparados en la juerga y en el vino querían seguir siendo lo que eran. Como camuflar la circuncisión de sus hijos en fiestas dónde cantaban, bailaban y bebían hasta coger una "tajá" (Una palabra que forma parte del vocabulario andaluz).

Está palabra alude a la embriaguez vinculada al acto sagrado de "tajar" o "retajar" el prepucio del pequeño.

Según fuentes del libro Antología de lo jondo.